# Couldn't find .apk file of my project in Dropbox

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I uploaded my project folder to Dropbox then I opened it with my galaxy tab as these steps:

```
Dropbox>>MyProject>>bin>>MyProject.apk
```

Then I clicked on .apk file  - it works, but when I updated my code then installed it again 
the .apk file is no longer there.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you compile your project as Android project then every time it create one .apk file. Some time old one is replaced by new one but some time two or more .apk file is appended on the bin folder so in this case just delete the old .apk file & upload it on your tablet.